# how to manage routes and Slides effect together in ionic?

Tags: routes, slide, ionic-framework

how can we manage routes and [slides](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/) together in ionic Framework.?
I mean that i have a page where three buttons are available i want that as user click on button new route\view show on same page but with effect of slide.
The main question is how to manage routing + slides together, slides effect on route change

**this is the three button code on index page**

```
 <div class="col">
            <div class="button-bar">
              <a class="button" ui-sref="app.home.tabs({name: 'ib'})" ui-sref-active="active">Ib</a>
              <a class="button" ui-sref="app.home.tabs({name: 'sr'})" ui-sref-active="active">Sr</a>
              <a class="button" ui-sref="app.home.tabs({name: 'komunitas'})" ui-sref-active="active">Ks</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**this will show view on same index page**

```
 <ui-view></ui-view>
```

**but i want that as user click on button a new route will load on same page but with slide effect**

Answer (score 0):

You can provide animation effect in css class, something like below

```
 -webkit-animation: slideInFromLeft .5s, fadeIn .5s;
    -moz-animation: slideInFromLeft .5s, fadeIn .5s;
    animation: slideInFromLeft .5s, fadeIn .5s;
```